# AngularJS withCredentials

Tags: angularjs

I've been working on an AngularJS project which has to send AJAX calls to an restfull webservice. This webservice is on another domain so I had to enable cors on the server. I did this by setting these headers:

```
cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8000");
cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
```

I'm able to send AJAX requests from AngularJS to the backend but I'm facing a problem when I try to get an attribute of a session. I believe this is because the sessionid cookie doesn't get send to the backend.

I was able to fix this in jQuery by setting withCredentials to true.

```
$("#login").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/api/login",
        data : '{"identifier" : "admin", "password" : "admin"}',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        type : 'POST',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
});

$("#check").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/api/ping",
        method: "GET",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
});
```

The problem that I'm facing is that I can't get this to work in AngularJS with the $http service. I tried it like this:

```
$http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/login", $scope.credentials, {withCredentials : true}).
            success(function(data) {
                $location.path('/');
                console.log(data);
            }).
            error(function(data, error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You should pass a configuration object, like so

```
$http.post(url, {withCredentials: true, ...})
```

or in older versions:

```
$http({withCredentials: true, ...}).post(...)
```

See also [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734686/communication-between-angularjs-and-a-jersey-webservice-which-are-on-a-different/14111039#14111039).

Comment: +1 and if you are using ngresource you would declare the method call with something like `'getUserDetail': { method:'GET', params: {}, withCredentials: true}`

Comment: In this case only withCredentials: true goes in that form or also options Content-Type, Accept, crossDomain, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials/Origin/Headers?

Comment: In this case older and newer version is?

Comment: @wanttobeprofessional I didn't check, feel free to suggest an edit if you find the exact boundaries.  This stuff was old in 2014…

Comment: Does anyone know, why this make such a huge difference? I compared all requests and responses (OPTIONS and POST) with and without `withCredentials` and could not find any difference. Maybe chrome's debug mode is hiding some details?

Comment: @wodzu Setting withCredentials to true allows the browser to send cookies with the request. Did your test requests have any cookies set?

Comment: @nevada_scout sorry, I moved on and don't even remember the context of my question

Answer (score 58):

In your app config function add this :

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

It will append this header for all your requests.

Dont forget to inject `$httpProvider`

## EDIT : 2015-07-29

Here is another solution :

HttpIntercepter can be used for adding common headers as well as common parameters.

Add this in your config :

`$httpProvider.interceptors.push('UtimfHttpIntercepter');`

and create factory with name `UtimfHttpIntercepter`

```
    angular.module('utimf.services', [])
    .factory('UtimfHttpIntercepter', UtimfHttpIntercepter)

    UtimfHttpIntercepter.$inject = ['$q'];
    function UtimfHttpIntercepter($q) {
    var authFactory = {};

    var _request = function (config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {}; // change/add hearders
        config.data = config.data || {}; // change/add post data
        config.params = config.params || {}; //change/add querystring params            

        return config || $q.when(config);
    }

    var _requestError = function (rejection) {
        // handle if there is a request error
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }

    var _response = function(response){
        // handle your response
        return response || $q.when(response);
    }

    var _responseError = function (rejection) {
        // handle if there is a request error
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }

    authFactory.request = _request;
    authFactory.requestError = _requestError;
    authFactory.response = _response;
    authFactory.responseError = _responseError;
    return authFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clarification:

```
$http.post(url, {withCredentials: true, ...})
```

should be

```
$http.post(url, data, {withCredentials: true, ...})
```

as per https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http