# withCredentials AngularJS request POST error

Tags: angularjs

I can't seem to send `$http.post` requests for authentication. My code matches the solution on this page [AngularJS withCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741533/angularjs-withcredentials)  but I get this error through my browser console.

```
Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials.
```

This is what the code looks like:

```
$scope.authenticate = function (user, pass) {
    $http.post(authUrl, {
        username: user,
        password: pass
    }, {
        withCredentials: true  
    })
}
```

I'm still new to angularJS but I read another site for help on setting custom headers, so I could fix the error message regarding the header. I tried to use:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = { 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : 'true' }
```

but I can't seem to get it right without `$httpProvider undefined` errors. I put it above the `$http.post` call, and also in the controller's function scope:

```
    .controller("authCtrl", function($scope, $http, authUrl, $httpProvider) {
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;`?

Comment: I just tried it. I get the same "undefined" error:  $httpProvider is not defined

Answer (score 1):

[From Angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers), you can only interact with providers during the configuration phase.

```
app.config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
});
```

Comment: I get the same error. It seems this boolean is set to true but the header is not being updated.   """Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is "". It must be 'true' to allow credentials."""

Answer (score 0):

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` must be set on the server. Further reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials