# Can not add bearer token in $resource header

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angular-http

I am not able to add bearer token in $resource service header for token based authentication. I used following code

**Factory**

```
return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/product/:id", null, {
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.getProfile().token
                }
            }
```

Also i tried below code as per some research in app.run

```
 $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + currentUser.getProfile().token;
```

But both options do not add this header in my request and i can see request in chrome without this headers and hence got unauthorized response. I am using angular 1.5.9. Any clue on this.

Comment: error in your console?

Comment: 401: unauthorised to access resource ../products

Comment: that's pretty obvious. are you getting the bearer token?

Comment: yes after login i got bearer token. I want to send this brearer token on subsequent requests.

Comment: is your header appends the Authorization when you look at your console?

Comment: No it is not captured in request header. thats what my worry is.

Comment: Try adding `withCredentials: true`. For more information, see [SO: AngularJS withCredentials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741533/angularjs-withcredentials)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `currentUser` is a service and `currentUser.getProfile()` is a synchronous API:

```
app.factory("myRestAPI", function(currentUser) {
    return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/product/:id", null, {
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                //REPLACE expression
                //'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.getProfile().token
                //WITH a function
                'Authorization': 
                      function() {
                          return 'Bearer ' + currentUser.getProfile().token;
                      }
            }
        }
    );
});
```

By using a function instead of an expression, the Authorization header will be computed on every call.

From the Docs:<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)</sup>

> - headers – {Object} – Map of strings or functions which return strings representing HTTP headers to send to the server. If the return value of a function is `null`, the header will not be sent. Functions accept a config object as an argument.

Comment: It is still not captured in request header.  Is there any issues with angular js version?

Comment: I got stuck with this exact issue and your answer saved a lot of time. Thanks!