# Browser won't store cookie

Tags: angular, http, cookies, setcookie, httpcookie

I'm running an angular 4 client on localhost:3000, which is communicating with a WEB API localhost:5000. My problem is, that I can't figure out why the browser refuses to store a cookie, when the server instructs it to do so.

**Client Request Headers**

```
Request URL:https://local.dev:5000/user/list?page=1&column=Email&listOrder=2
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:5000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-NZ,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json
DNT:1
Host:local.dev:5000
Origin:https://localhost:3000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://localhost:3000/user
```

**Server Response Headers:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://localhost:3000
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
credentials:include
Date:Tue, 09 May 2017 08:22:25 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Kestrel
Set-Cookie: <cookiename>=<somedata>; expires=Tue, 09 May 2017 09:22:23 GMT; domain=local.dev; path=/; secure; httponly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin
withCredentials:true
```

As you can see CORS is also enabled. HTTPS is used for transmission. Also tried without setting an expiration date. The cookie's domain is set to `local.dev`. I also tried with `/` and `localhost`.

Afterwards Chrome's debug view does not display the cookie. Just some default angular cookie. Therefore I assume the set-cookie header is ignored for some reason.

[image: chrome debug view. cookie not stored]

HELP!

Comment: Did you specify that cookies should be accepted for cross-domain requests in your API call?

Comment: I'm not sure. How do I achieve that?

Comment: That’s what the `withCredentials` flag of XMLHttpRequest is for. (How that translates into angular, please research yourself.)

Comment: @CBroe `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is `true` on the server's repsonse if that's what you mean.

Comment: No, it is not what I mean. What I wrote is what I mean.

Comment: well, thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS withCredentials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741533/angularjs-withcredentials)

Comment: @Cbroe and thanks for the downvote :)

Comment: @CBroe ok, I forgot to save the file. setting the parameter worked. so if you write an answer I will gladly accept it :) thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For cross-domain AJAX requests, you need to explicitly specify that cookies should be send with the request, and accepted in the response.

This is done using the `withCredentials` flag of the XMLHttpRequest object.

In Angular, you can set it as an option of the `$http` service, see also [AngularJS withCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741533/angularjs-withcredentials)

Comment: I don't see any difference in neither request and response headers, do you know why it is important to explicitly set that option? I thought the browser is repsonsible to store the cookie and not the application itself.

Comment: You should see a difference in request headers, if you are sending cookies, or additional credentials such as for HTTP Auth. In the response you don’t see a difference, because the server tries to set the cookie anyway. The withCredentials flag determines whether the browser _accepts_ that cookie from the response header for cross-domain requests.