# CORS domain cookie for AngularJS and Spring boot application

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, cookies, cross-domain

Currently I am building a application using AngularJS 1.6 (http://localhost:8000), and Spring boot (http://localhost:8080). When the user log in, the spring boot api will add a cookie in the response, and I can see the cookie in the browser.

Then in another request to get the user, my backend code use

```
httpServletRequest.getCookies()
```

to get the cookie, but it always returns null.

When I used jsp and spring boot, it works well. So I am wondering if it is a cross domain issue.

In the backend, I already added the configuration:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: if you are using the cookie for validation, you can read the cookie from the frontend(angularjs) and add it to a header of the get user call. Then from backend(spring boot), you can try to read the cookie from the service call header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the withCredentials option in AngularJS?

If you add this configuration, the angular $http service will send the cookie when sending the request.

For example:

```
$http.post(url, {withCredentials: true, ...})
```

or add this configuration for all requests:

```
 angular.module('myApp')
 .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}])
```

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials
2. [AngularJS withCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741533/angularjs-withcredentials)