# Angular Spring Boot Cookies on localhost

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, cookies

I have Angular 7 as frontend and Spring Boot as backend.

Angular app hosted on localhost:4200 and Spring app hosted on localhost:8080

On user login, I'm saving a spring session and a cookie is returned. When the user tries to login again, I first check whether the session exists.

For this, the cookie is required from the client. But I'm not getting any cookie in the client request.

In Chrome dev tools, Application tab, following cookie can be seen:

[image]

In Spring Boot's application.properties, I have:

```
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
server.servlet.session.timeout=60
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION
server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age=2592000
```

In controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(allowCredentials = "true", origins = {"http://localhost:4200", "http://127.0.0.1:4200"})
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UsersController {    
    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if(cookies != null) {
          for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
              String cookieName = cookies[i].getName();
              String cookieValue = cookies[i].getValue();
              logger.info("UsersController - cookie - {} {}", cookieName, cookieValue);
           }
        }
        HttpSession springsession = request.getSession(false);
        if (springsession != null) {
            logger.info("UsersController - login - session exists");            
            ...
        }       

        logger.info("UsersController - login - session does not exist");
        ...
    }
```

I'm not getting any cookie in the client request.

Whereas when I try multiple login requests from the Postman, it works.

So why doesn't it work from browser?

I have tried setting server.servlet.session.cookie.domain property to null, false, 127.0.0.1. But none worked.

How can this be solved?

Comment: whats the spring session strategy is it header or cookie based ?

Comment: @Barath cookie based

Comment: @Barath There is no additional configuration.  @ SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
 }
}

Comment: @Barath there are not much logs available. The application prints UsersController - login - session does not exist

Comment: can you enable the logs ```logging.level.org.springframework.session=debug``` and share it. check for this ```No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.```

Comment: @Barath Yes, I'm getting: No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.

Comment: @Barath the issue seems to be of browsers handling of cookies, most likely because it is localhost

Comment: @Barath Angular app hosted on localhost:4200 and Spring app hosted on localhost:8080

Comment: @Barath network tab details for first login request https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Sdr.png

Comment: @Barath cookies are actually passed as part of the request

Comment: @Barath it cannot be seen in the request. But can be seen in Application tab cookies.

Comment: @Barath yes, this.http.get(entity.url)

Comment: ok I think its strange but I could clearly see cookies are not passed as part of the request. cookies must get passed as part of the request even though it is present in application tab. check the network tab always cookies will get passed. Try to debug whether http is configured with credentials property.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing exactly the same issue, did you solve it ?

Comment: @TCH unfortunately not

Comment: I think this guy is on the same issue as us, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51696601/cors-domain-cookie-for-angularjs-and-spring-boot-application. I changed .allowCredentials(*true*) in the CORS configuration of my backend but so far it is not enough to make it work. I still cannot get cookies from in my backend when requests come from the frontend. But with Postman everything works